# Using input value with onkeyup to innerHTML a div

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

i have been watching some questions here about the same topic but i cant make my code works with the solutions,

I have a dynamic tr table, what i want to do is when i write on the last input of each row a div "result" overwrite like the values, that because i want to make later a connection that shows me users name on my db, like a data live search

JS

```
function createTable() {
        var a;
        var r;

        a = document.getElementById('tb1').value;
        var length = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
        if (a == "") {
            alert("Please enter some numeric value");
        } else {
            var change = document.getElementById("trow1").style.visibility = 'visible';
            //var change = document.getElementById("trow2").style.visibility = 'visible';
            var changet = document.getElementById("table").style.visibility = 'visible';
            var rows = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            r=i+length;
            let tr = document.createElement("tr");
            tr.innerHTML = "<td>"+r+"</td><td><input type='text' id='" + "parameter".concat(r) + "'></td><td id='tdlmin'><input type='text' id='" + "lmin".concat(r) + "'></td><td  id='tdlmax'><input type='text' id='" + "lmax".concat(r) + "'></td><td><input type='text' id='" + "level".concat(r) + "'></td><td><select id='" + "relcal".concat(r) + "' style='width:100%;'><option value='NA'>NA</option><option value='SI'>SI</option></select></td><td><input type='text' id='" + "comment".concat(r) + "' cols=100></td><td><input type='text' id='" + "procown".concat(r) + "' onkeyUp='document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = this.value;'></div></td>";
            document.getElementById("table").appendChild(tr);
            }   
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row align-items-start">
<div class="col-9">
    Numero de Parametros: <input type="text" id="tb1"/>
    <button type="button" onclick='createTable()'>Crear</button>
    <table id="table" class="order-table table"  name="table1" required style="visibility:hidden;">
        <tr id="trow1" style="visibility:hidden; text-align: center;"><td>#</td><td>Parametro</td><td colspan="2"><table><tr><td colspan="2">Limite</td></tr><tr><td>Min.</td><td>Max.</td></tr></table></td><td><table style="width: 100%;"><tr><td>Nivel</td></tr><tr><td>1 - 4</td></tr></table></td><td>Relevante Calidad</td><td>Comentario</td><td>Dueño del Proceso</td></tr>

    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick='subir()'>Subir Parametros</button>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
    <div id="result" name="result"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit:
This is what i have tried yet:

```
$('"'+procownid+'"').on("keyup",function(){
            var userlike = document.getElementById(procownid).value;
            alert(userlike);
        });
        $("#table tr").on('keyup', procownid, function({
        var userlike = document.getElementById(procownid).value;
            alert(userlike);    
            result.innerHTML="<p>"+userlike+"</p>"
        });
        alert(userlike);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML="<p>userlike:"+uselike+"</p>";
        $.post('getUser',{accion:"ListarUserTPMD",userlike:userlike}, function(data){
        result.innerHTML=data;
            });
```

my question is, i can get that when i write on the input it trigger the onkeyup and show me for example the input.value, why i cant make it write on the div?

Comment: Try `event.key` instead of `this.value`

Comment: ok, now i can write on the result div, just a question, this only writes the last character i write, but i want to use all the input.value that the users has wrote

Comment: Try `input.value + event.key`

Comment: `uselike` is that spelled correctly? Seems like it's missing an `r`